# Webhook returns internal server error connecting Paypal to WooCommerce

Tags: zapier

I need to use the Paypal IPN for two services. So, following the Zapier guide, I created a Webhook that sends a POST request to this URL https://italianindie.com/?wc-api=WC_Gateway_Paypal. It's the WooCommerce IPN URL for Paypal.

I've been using the same URL for months and it works. Orders and refunds are correctly processed.

But when I test the Zap, it gets an internal server error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add a stack trace or some code snippet describing your error.

Comment: Sorry, I don't even know how to get it. I was sent here by the support.